# Required = "true" function is causing problems

Tags: jsf

If I register without filling in the required fields, the program does not work

//save

```
<p:commandLink title="Kaydet" actionListener="{workLogDetailBean.saveWorkLog}"
 class="TextDecNone"process="@this frmworklog" update="content">
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-save Fs20" ></i></p:commandLink>
```

//in form

```
 <p:inputTextarea autoResize="false" placeholder="Açıklama Giriniz..." maxlength="200"  required="true"
                                         counterTemplate="{0} karakter kaldı" value="#{workLogDetailBean.workLog.workDesc}"
                                         style="width: 100%; height: 100px; font-size: 17px !important;"/>
```

//I want to update this part  Note :in form

```
 <p:columnGroup>
  < p:inputText id="activityid" title="Aktivite kodu" placeholder="Aktivite seçiniz..." value="#{workLogDetailBean.workLog.activityId}" style="float:left;"/>
      <p:commandLink  styleClass="white-button" process="@this" onstart="PF('frmactivity').show()" title="Arama"               style="float:right; margin-top: -30px;">  i class="icon-search Fs20" ></i>
 </p:commandLink> </p:columnGroup>



<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{bean.activityRelationSelect}"
update="#{update}" oncomplete="PF('frmactivity').hide()"/>
```

Comment: what are the problems you get?

Comment: `the program does not work`, be more precise

Comment: activityid is not updating :(

Comment: problem solved
`<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{bean.activityRelationSelect}"
**process="@this #{update}"** update="#{update}" oncomplete="PF('frmactivity').hide()"/>`